# haskell reading a vector of pairs from bytestring very slow, how to make it faster?

Tags: performance, haskell, vector, bytestring

I am trying to read a large vector of custom data type from a binary file. I tried to use the [example given here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.7.6.1/docs/Data-Binary-Get.html).

The trouble with the example code is, it uses lists and I want to use vectors.
So I adapted that code as below, but it takes very long time (more than a minute, I gave up after that) to read even 1 MB file.

```
module Main where

import Data.Word
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BIN
import Data.Binary.Get
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as Vec

main = do
  b <- BIN.readFile "dat.bin" -- about 1 MB size file
  let v = runGet getPairs (BIN.tail b) -- skip the first byte
  putStrLn $ show $ Vec.length v

getPair :: Get (Word8, Word8)
getPair = do
  price <- getWord8
  qty <- getWord8
  return (price, qty)

getPairs :: Get (Vec.Vector (Word8, Word8))
getPairs = do
 empty <- isEmpty
 if empty
   then return Vec.empty
   else do pair  <- getPair
           pairs <- getPairs
           return (Vec.cons pair pairs) -- is it slow because V.cons is O(n)?
```

When I tried to run it with `ghc --make -O2 pairs.hs` I got the error `Stack space overflow: current size ...`

How to efficiently read pairs of values from bytestring into vector?

Again, I wish to get complete working code not just only pointers to Haskell site or RWH nor a just list of function/module names.

Comment: you shouldn't _demand_ a complete working solution as answer. SO is a learning and problem understanding site not a crowd sourced coding service.

Comment: @ErikAllik I am demanding complete working solution in the same spirit of Smallest Complete Working Example. Also I do give minimum working example. Another reason is the rarity of working examples on the Haskell sites. The problems I ask solutions for are generally very small snippets, hardly sufficient to accusing me of crowd sourcing code. The SO is great and Haskell docuemntation is poor is why I need to make that _demand_. I apologize if it has hurt/offended or caused undue distress to someone.

Comment: Yes, this is slow because `V.cons` is O(n). What did you expect? A million times a million is a lot! `vector` has perfectly good documentation. Note that the documentation for a Hackage module generally has a table of contents in the upper right. Check out the section on constructing vectors.

Comment: @dfeuer I expected it to be slow. But I didn't know any other method to construct the vector by incrementally adding elements to it as I go on reading values from the bytestring. As for why did I ask the question: I didn't understand any other method given on the hackage that can allow me to incrementally construct the vector as desired.

Comment: Well, you basically *can't* construct a vector by incrementally adding to it! They're more like C or C++ arrays or FORTRAN vectors than like the flexible things some other environments call vectors. You can get such flexible things in Haskell if you like; the traditional one is `Data.Sequence`, but Ed Kmett's been working on some faster ones lately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of examples of creating Vectors from files. They are not the most efficient, but both run in just a couple of seconds in ghci.

```
module Main where

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BIN
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as Vec
import System.IO
import System.Posix

getFileSize :: String -> IO Int
getFileSize path = do
    stat <- getFileStatus path
    return (fromEnum $ fileSize stat)

readVector1 path = do
  size <- getFileSize path
  withBinaryFile path ReadMode $ \h -> do
    -- can also use: size <- hFileSize h
    let go _ = do bs <- BS.hGet h 2 
                  return (BS.index bs 0, BS.index bs 1)
    Vec.generateM (div size 2) go

pairs (a:b:rest) = (a,b) : pairs rest
pairs _          = []

readVector2 path = do
  contents <- BIN.readFile path
  -- unfoldr :: Unbox a => (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> Vector a
  let v = Vec.unfoldr go (pairs $ BIN.unpack contents)
        where go [] = Nothing
              go (p:ps) = Just (p, ps)
  return v

main = do
  v <- readVector1 "rand" -- large file
  print $ Vec.length v
  v <- readVector2 "rand"
  print $ Vec.length v
```

A third alternative:

```
readVector3 path = do
  contents <- BS.readFile path
  let size = BS.length contents
      v = Vec.generate (div (fromIntegral size) 2) go
            where go i = let a = BS.index contents (2*i)
                             b = BS.index contents (2*i+1)
                         in (a,b)
  return v
```

This one turns out to be the fastest of the three.

Comment: Note that using `size <- hFileSize h` might be a more portable way to get a file's size and doesn't require `System.Posix`

Comment: the `readVector2` function uses lists and `readVector1` is too much work in IO.

Comment: Both run in less than a second when compiled on my machine. How long does it take on yours?

Comment: @user5402: You changed quite a bit about the code - would you mind explaining what the most important change(s) was/were for improving the performance? (I'm curious)

Comment: I think the main takeaway is that Vec.cons is probably inefficient. At first I though you should tell Vector the length you need - hence the first version. However, `unfold` also works pretty well. The main difference between `unfoldr` and `cons` is that `unfoldr` appends to a vector which is a more natural operation and thus I think more efficient. `cons`, however, I believe has to prepend to a vector which is not the natural way for vectors to grow.

Comment: No. unfoldr just uses the traditional array doubling trick to achieve O(1) amortized time per `snoc` even though it may have to double the size of the array several times, copying the whole thing each time.

Comment: Yeah - but my point it that it seems to be a _lot_ better than using `cons`.

Comment: Well yes, certainly it is! But the same technique could be applied to fill a vector from back to front instead. `cons` has to copy the whole vector each time. `unfoldr` saves itself some wiggle room so it can afford the occasional copy without blowing the asymptotic bound. Prepend vs. append has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @user5402 I liked and upvoted your answer but what bothers me is the IO part in the `readVector1`. If you give the code for reading vector that just takes ByteString (you can find its size) and then returns a vector filled in with the values I will accept it. I am struggling myself to get that type of code using your code but unable to remove the IO from it.

Comment: Ok - watch this space.

Comment: Have a look at `readVector3`. Adjust the offset formulas `2*i`, `2*i+1` and the length determination `div size 2` to account for any header bytes you want to skip over.

Comment: @user5402 I accept this answer. I cannot upvote it more than once. You have taught me many things thru the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative approach for loading the vector, that uses `pipes` and `pipes-bytestring` to stream the file, and the [`vector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.1.1/docs/Control-Foldl.html#v:vector) function from `foldl` to create the vector:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PackageImports #-}
import Data.Functor (void)
import "pipes" Pipes
import qualified "pipes" Pipes.Prelude as P
import qualified "pipes-bytestring" Pipes.ByteString as B
import qualified "pipes-binary" Pipes.Binary as B
import qualified "vector" Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
import qualified "foldl" Control.Foldl as L
import "lens-family-core" Lens.Family (view)
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
    v <- withBinaryFile "somefile" ReadMode (\h ->
        -- for simplicity, errors are ignored with "void"
        L.impurely P.foldM L.vector (void (view B.decoded (B.drop 1 (B.fromHandle h)))))
    print (V.length (v::V.Vector (B.Word8,B.Word8)))
```

`cons` is inefficient. The approach taken by `foldl`'s `vector` is to progressively double the vector's capacity using [`unsafeGrow`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Generic-Mutable.html#v:unsafeGrow), in order to accomodate incoming values, and at the end "trim" any excess capacity with [`unsafeTake`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Mutable.html#v:unsafeTake).

Comment: It's an elegant solution - I really like it, but when I benchmark it takes about 2 secs to consume a 1 MB file whereas the reading two bytes at a time method takes about about 0.1 secs. Is that what you're seeing?